# CSS table-row not expanding 100% inside table-cell

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a widget with a tabular structure and I'm not seeing why the two rows on the right are not expanding to full width (or why they don't have a red border around them).

My goal is for the black horizontal rule to run between rows 1 and 2 and reach the far right end of the entire table.

[**Demo Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/3qeyedjv/1/)

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#cell1 {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 30px;
  border: 1px dashed orange;
}
#cell1 > #line1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#cell1 > #line2 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#cell1 > #line3 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#cell2 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed orange;
}
#cell2 > #topRow {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black; // horizontal rule
}
#cell2 > #bottomRow {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">

  <div id="cell1">
    <span id="line1">line 1</span>
    <br>
    <span id="line2">line 2</span>
    <br>
    <span id="line3">line 3</span>
  </div>


  <div id="cell2">
    <div id="topRow">
      This is the top row
    </div>

    <div id="bottomRow">
      This is the bottom row
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `display: table-row` is not needed. Why did you think you needed you set the `display` at all? Just leave it as default (which, for a `div` is `block`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display:table-row` to make the bottom border visible

or use:

```
<div id="topRow">
    This is the top row
</div>
<hr />
<div id="bottomRow">
    This is the bottom row
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is create one full width row with your `<hr>` within it.

```
<tr><!-- table row 100% width -->
<hr></hr>
</tr>
```

Your defining a new full width table row with only the horizontal rule running through it.

---

Actually it appears you aren't even using tables, so this is kind of an odd question - but, in your case just make a full width `div` with the `<hr>` within it, or position the hr `absolute` with a higher `z-index` by adding a selector directly to hr element.

Comment: Could you show me please? I'm not sure what you mean.